# puppeteer await page.$$('.className'), but I get only the first 11 element with that class, why?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

the code that I am using to scrape a student list:

```
let collection1 = await page.$$('div.layout-2DM8Md')
  console.log("Student Online:")
  for (let el of collection1) {
    let name = await el.$eval(('div.name-uJV0GL'), node => node.innerText.trim());
    console.log(name)
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because the contents of rest of those elements are loaded dynamically with a Javascript framework like React or Vue. This means that it only gets loaded when those elements enter the viewport of the browser.

To fix this you will need to write a function that auto scrolls the page so that those elements can get into the viewport and then you have to wait for that function to finish before you collect the data.

The scrolling function:

```
const autoScroll = async(page) => {
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var totalHeight = 0;
            var distance = 100;
            var timer = setInterval(() => {
                var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                totalHeight += distance;

                if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight){
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    resolve();
                }
            }, 30);
        });
    });
}
```

Then call this function **after** `page.goto()` and **before** you grab the content with `page.content()`. I also set the viewport width and height then the scrolling goes a little faster:

```
await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load'});
await page.setViewport({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800
});
await autoScroll(page); // The scroll function
const html = await page.content()
```

Comment: Thank you bro, you nailed it, I have a question related to your solution, you said that the rest of the elements get loaded only when they entered the view-port of the browser is this method applied to enhance the user's experience? is it related the lazy loading?

Comment: Awesoooome @OussamaAlGhamian I'm glad it's working! Yeah it's like lazy loading. It makes the loading time faster if it loads only what you need at a time, which makes for a better user experience, especially when someone's connection isn't that fast. This is happens with images a lot. In some cases it's just lazy loading and some cases it's the framework. Some sites do not employ this method in which case you won't have to scroll down to grab the content. Hope it helps  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯